# How to move files without disrupting program using them

Tags: linux

I have a directory holding many files (100k+), and a program that is working on them (writing/reading etc, but it does not create new ones). I'd like to move those files (to another filesystem, so hardlinks are not an option) without disrupting running program (I can accept if it has to wait on IO sometimes a bit, but it should not halt). Basically what I need, is some magic that will move file and leave symlink in place in one atomic step, even if the file is being open at the moment. Linux kernel is 3.14.79, filesystem is NFS (and EXT3 on NFS server)

Comment: The answer may depend on the program involved, how it opened the files, if it watches file (especially inode changes), etc. You should really try to reach a situation where you can change stuff when the program is stopped.

Comment: No, it does not watch files. As I wrote - it just do read/writes.